# If color is not found in PixelSearch, send (LEFT) until color is found? | AUTOIT

Tags: autoit

I am trying to search for a certain assigned pixel color in a certain window frame and I want the script to send the command arrow key left until color is found and then proceed with "attacking." Here is my code.

```
   Func getColor()
   $point = MouseGetPos()
   $color = PixelGetColor($point[0], $point[1])
   MsgBox(0, "Color Set", "The color has been set to " & $color)
EndFunc

Func attackLoop()
   MsgBox(0, "Attacking", "Starting to attack")
   While 1
          $point = PixelSearch(60, 157, 1772, 759, $color)
          if IsArray($point) Then
                 MouseClick("left", $point[0], $point[1])
                 Sleep($interval)
          EndIf
          Sleep(50)
   WEnd
EndFunc

While 1
   sleep(250)
WEnd
```

What would I have to add to achieve my title?

Comment: Try PixelSearch(0, 0, @ DesktopWidth, @ DesktopHeight, $color)
and maybe add a shade variation. but be careful or you will end up restarting your pc while it clicks away thru your monitor :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your examples should include a more "full" set of functions, as by testing your code on any of our systems both `$color` and `$interval` will return  an error because the variables haven't been set.

Secondly, instead of using "While 1" in your attack loop, it might be better do an while loop like:

```
$point = PixelSearch(60, 157, 1772, 759, $color)
While IsArray($point)
    $point = PixelSearch(60, 157, 1772, 759, $color)
    MouseClick("left", $point[0], $point[1])
    Sleep($interval)
WEnd
```

OR

```
While PixelSearch(60, 157, 1772, 759, $color)
    $point = PixelSearch(60, 157, 1772, 759, $color)
    MouseClick("left", $point[0], $point[1])
    Sleep($interval)
WEnd
```